# Webform route values with '&'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I'm using routes in my web application. currently, I have an issue where a route value contains '&' within it. Even though i encode the URL its still throwing potentially dangerous request error.

Here is the Encoded URL

```
http://localhost:4185/ViewAttachment/K200000000025263/Correspondence%20%26amp%3B%20testing/pdf
```

Is there anyway I can get past this? I have seen some solutions where we need to define Invalidchar in request in web.config file but not sure what are downsides to doing this? Is there another way that i need to encode my route parameters?

Comment: This looks *HTML-encoded* instead of *URL-encoded*.  How are you encoding it?  What do you expect the decoded URL to be?

Comment: Im encoding using the javascript encodeURI() method

Comment: What was the original URL value?  It's definitely strange that it had an `&amp;` in it, since that's HTML and has no business in a URL.  It sounds like the problem is before you get to where the error is happening.

Comment: Here is the original URL: http://localhost:4185/ViewAttachment/K200000000025263/Correspondence%20&%20testing/pdf

Comment: That appears to be already *partially* encoded, and a fully encoded version would be `http://localhost:4185/ViewAttachment/K200000000025263/Correspondence%20%26%20testing/pdf`  What is it that you expect the final decoded URL to be?

Comment: yes, but javascript encodeURI is generating the other i already posted. i tried encodeURIComponents but still same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134534/discussion-between-krishna-and-david).

Comment: Something appears to be mangling the URL before you get to this point.  You're going to want to look at the bigger picture of where this value is originating, what that original value is, and what modifications are being made to it along the way.  *Some* characters have been encoded, others have *not*.  I don't know what in your code might be causing this, or perhaps the original value was bad to begin with.  You may need to first run it through a *decode* before you encode it in order to repair that damage.

Comment: i will look into it more but as FYI i tried to use the URL you posted and still got the same potentially dangerous request error